# Lightbox like overlay effect to display a hidden DIV on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on web page and when I'm browsing for inspiration i cam across with this site, which uses a **which uses overlay effect to display and hidden DIV on click**, I like to use this type of effect on my site also.
any idea how to do will be highly appreciated.

this link will take you to the relevant web site.
[The site i came across.](http://pacelaw.com/#focus)

Comment: Just search for "lightbox plugin". Most implementations will have an option for this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like that:

In the HTML-code:

```
<div class="overlay">

    [whatever you want to display in the overlay DIV]

</div>
```

In the CSS-Code:

```
div.overlay {
    width: 650px;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    left: calc(50% - 340px);
    top: calc(50% - 230px);
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s;
    transition: opacity 1.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

All other design things (such as font-family, color etc) go in that, too.

**Code-Explanation**
width: 650px - The boxes width
height: 400px - The boxes height
position: fixed - it doesn't scroll
left: calc(50% - 340px) - It's located in the middle
top: calc(50% - 230px) - It's located in the middle
border-radius: 15px - Make it round-rect
z-index: 999 - It's on top every time (Make sure others have lower z-indexes).
transition: opacity 1.5s - Makes it fading in
opacity: 0 - Makes it invisible

So, for now the box is completely invisible. You can make it visible using javascript:

```
function open() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.opacity = 1;
}
function close() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

The Last step you'll have to do is calling the function in your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="open()">Open</a>
```

and in your Box a Link to close:

```
<a href="#" onClick="close()">Close</a>
```

Another possible way, in my opinion the user-friendlier way, is to make another  with the class background. That gets onClick="close". The code can look like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="background" onClick="close()"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.dark {
    position:fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then you have to add the following in the open() function:

```
document.getElementById("background").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("background").style.opacity = 1;
```

And in the close() Function:

```
document.getElementById("background").style.opacity = 0;
document.getElementById("background").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

If you do it like that, when the visitor clicks anywhere on the page, except on the overlay, it'll fade out. The background also makes the page a bit darker while the overlay is open, so the visitor will concentrate on the overlay box. If you don't want to make the page darker, change

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

to

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I wish you good luck with your web-page and I hope I was able to help you!

Comment: First of all i would like to apologize for the late reply I was out work for few days for some personal matter, I must say that you answer was very helpful it was very detailed and clear. thank you once again for your advice.

Comment: It says "div.dark" for the CSS definition, but the HTML <div> is class="background". I think they need to be the same.

Comment: @rmetzger That is actually true.